# Quicktime X - How to hide mouse during screen capture?

Tags: ios-simulator, mouse, hide, quicktime, screen-capture

I am attempting to record an app demo on the simulator, and want to use the Quicktime screen capture feature. However, I would like to hide the mouse during the capture.
Is this possible? 
Doesn't seem to be a built in feature, so I am assuming I need to use some sort of plugin or hack.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture iOS Simulator video for App Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797990/capture-ios-simulator-video-for-app-preview)

Answer (score 16):

QuickTime itself does not seem to offer this functionality therefore you have to resort to some other means to hide the cursor. On OSX there are some tools that allow this.

[Cursourcerer](http://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer-hide-your-cursor-at-will/) is the first that springs to mind. However, as this really hides the cursor, it might not be ideal as you yourself will not be able to see what you are doing.

However, if you do not need to use QuickTime per se, it seems there are commercial screen recording solutions allowing this sort of thing such as [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm). I am not affiliated but the price seems reasonable and there is a demonstration of desired behavior [here](http://youtu.be/KHs-ccHSpdg).

Comment: Cursorcerer is working great for my use case, which involves having to see the mouse to place it somewhere, turning off the cursor, recording the screen and click dragging with a slight movement up, down, left, or right. For an added plus, you can toggle the cursor on or off with a hotkey that you set.

Answer (score 12):

You don't record your app in your computer, but directly on your iPad or iPhone, connected to your Mac with a lightning cable. Then in Quicktime you select the "New movie recording" option (instead of "New screen recording"), then you will be able to select your iPad/iPhone as the "camera" and start recording your app running in your iOS device without any mouse pointer.

Comment: I had no idea this was possible - very handy for app videos.

Comment: In fact, this is the method recommended by Apple to create app preview videos. Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/

Comment: Using your device connected to quick time won't record screen taps though - I've seen suggestions to turn on accessibility features to do that, but that doesn't look very good. What's the best way to record screen taps as well?

Answer (score 6):

https://obsproject.com/
OBS can record your app window, and it ignores the cursor on the window. 
Useful even if you are not a youtuber.

Answer (score 2):

`Cursorcerer` for 10.14+ ⇨
http://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer-hide-your-cursor-at-will/

`MouseHider.app` for 10.13 and earlier ⇨ https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mouse-hider/id894419721?mt=12

I use `option+command+k` (`⌥+⌘+k`) to show / hide. It works globally.

It's also useful to hide the mouse cursor when you do the `control-scroll` zoom trick to focus in on a video.