# Apple Store App Preview Video Resolution

Tags: ios, store, preview, imovie

I am trying to make a video for App Preview in Apple App Store.
I created video using QuickTime Player, making a screencast of simulator.
After doing this i imported this video to iMovie and performed some changes.
I now want to export this video for App Store, but iMovie doesn't offer the resolution of 640x1136 for shared video as a file.

I exported in highest resolution and imported in QuickTime Player again. QuickTime Player has option to export video for iPhone 5, iPAd 2 etc. So i tried that, but the resolution stays the same only file format has changed.

How can i create 640x1136 resolution video that is created in iMovie or are there some alternatives?

SOLUTION:

Thanks, i ended with camtasia. I exported HD imovie video file to camtasia and cropped the video to desired resolution. Export worked!

One more option:
https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/

Comment: Why does anybody downrate this question? It is really a painful process to get videos and screenshots to the right dimensions. Thank you for the hint with camtasia.

Comment: Look to my answer below for how to solve this using only iMovie and QuickTime. It is a solution that matches your original requirements.

Answer (score 25):

If your original video is the wrong dimensions for the app store - here is a trick using just iMovie and Quicktime to get the right dimensions.

1. Use QuickTime to record a short clip from the size of the device you need
2. Use iMovie and insert that clip into a new "App Preview" project
3. Add your actual video after the short clip

Now, any clips that you export will be in the right dimensions.

If you need to hide your short clip, you can shorten it to 0.1 seconds. Put a title over it and delete the text. Now your video starts with 0.1 seconds of a black screen.

NOTE: @Spoek's comment below is worth noting - adding an image of the right dimensions works too and creates a freeze frame. @SpaceMonkeys comment below as well - you can delete the image after adding it.

Comment: Will this be approved by Apple in AppStore?

Comment: Yes. We have had half a dozen videos approved in the app store by taking this approach.

Comment: Sweet :) This is by far the easiest approach. You can also just add an image with the correct dimensions as the first 0.1sec of the movie. And remove the "zooming" effect that is applied by default, to get a freeze frame.

Comment: You don't even need the first frame to be there. Just add an image with the right dimensions at the beginning. Copy and paste your video. Delete the first image and voila, you're good to go.

Comment: I don't have a physical device that would give me the correct dimensions, so I used this answer combined with the accepted answer on this question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797990/capture-ios-simulator-video-for-app-preview

I used the simulator to take a 0.1s video in the correct size.

Comment: This trick did worked in the past, this time Apple rejected my app because of the black frame it adds. Unfortunately I had to remove the preview as my app requires camera so cannot use simulator

Answer (score 16):

1) Download Squared - MPEG Streamclip: http://www.squared5.com

2) Then open your video file with it.

3) Click "File" > "Export to Quicktime"

4) Set your desired resolution

5) Export it

6) Then double click the exported file and Quicktime will go through a "converting" process.  This step is very important.  If you don't have Quicktime convert it, the upload will fail in iTunes connect.  It will save it as a new file called "YourFile - Converted"  (It took me a whole day to realize this!)

7) Upload the converted file to iTunes connect!

That should work!  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, i ended with camtasia, but i am going to try your solution

Comment: After `Export to Quick Time...` in `MPEG Streamclip` you need to set frame size accordingly,  set `Frame Rate` 30, I usually set `No Sound`, `Compression` H-264

Comment: Tried your solution. Unfortunately Squared5 cropped of the upper quarter of the screen.

Comment: This worked for me, exporting it from Steamclip as an MP4 but iTunesConnect was claiming the dimensions were wrong. I fixed it by openeing the clip in iMovie and then exporting it as an App Preview.

Answer (score 16):

All you need to do is open iMovie > File > New App Preview.
[image]

When you finish editing, click on the share button on the upper right and there's an option "App Preview". It will give you the right resolution if you record the screen with your iOS devices.

[image]

Comment: So you just need to upload 1 resolution for it to be seen on all devices in the App Store?

Comment: @EricChuang I recorded with different devices that my app supports and use iMovie -> App Preview to finalize them.

Comment: I think this should be the recommended answer. The template is 'App Preview' All you need to do is change what device you record on to get the resolution needed.

Comment: I did exactly this, as per Apple Documentation: Recorded a QuickTime movie from my iPhone; Selected New App Preview in iMovie and dropped in the .mov from QuickTime; Shared as an App Preview; and end up with 750x1334 resolution.  The problems is Apple App Store wants 886x1920!

Answer (score 2):

The solution that @Praxiteles gives is the easiest by far, I just used images instead of video as @Spoek's mentioned.

I just made black images for each resolution needed in GIMP and dropped them at the beginning and made them .01 seconds.

So I only had to make two videos (iPhone & iPad) and just copied the elements from one iMovie project to the next. This is instead of making separate videos for iPhone 5,iPhone 6, iPhone 6+, & iPad.

This saved me a ton of work.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What size did you make the two videos? Did he two sizes prevent any black bars from appearing at the edge of your videos?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the iPad 3rd Generation has an on-screen 'Home' button.You'll need another preview for it, even though the resolution is the same as the 2nd generation. If you've used 'safe areas' in your screen designs to avoid the button,  your app may appear differently on the two devices. Apple's latest spec does suggest they're not accepting one as an alternative for the other. See:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8

Answer (score 0):

### Answer 2020

For App Preview Resolutions
Pls check apple's official docs here, it is very clear what size you need to have for your videos

I spent a lot of time to find this...

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8

Comment: What do they mean by "native" and "accepted" resolution?