# App review video related device

Tags: ios, iphone, video, app-store-connect

I need some help
I am doing submission on Apple store
I would like to attach also video to my app preview
I recorded one on my device, but now I have to attach same video also for other device types, i.e. iPhone 6, 6+ etc, that I do not own. 
I would like to know if there is a software that resize my video to a correct dimensions since I cannot use the same video for all device types because they told me dimensions are not correct.
I guess this is a common issue because I do not believe everybody has all devices to make simple app preview video
Hope someone can give an advice
Looking forward to it
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I used [Movie Clips Free](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/movie-clips-free/id914401591?mt=12) from the Mac AppStore. It can help you resizing, rotating, cropping *(etc...)* the video.

I needed some time to learn how it works until I got a satisfying result. And it's **free**.

Remember that you won't get professional results though.

You can give it a try...

Comment: tried a lot but i guess it do not wok properly. i was interested in cropping but when esporting files, size it is not the one i was looking for. are you sure? ever used for an actual app review?

Comment: I used it for App Preview once, yes. But the resolution isn't very good. At that time I couldn't find anything better (for free).

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it.
Please look at these links:

[Capture iOS Simulator video for App Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797990/capture-ios-simulator-video-for-app-preview)
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX

Do not remember to use also Hand Brake.

Really tricky. Not good at all.

Bye.