# iPhoneX AppStore Video Preview

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-x

If you don't have an iPhoneX device and would like to add video to your appstore video preview, how can one do so? You can use quickTime player to capture video directly from your device and use iMovie to export it in Appstore Preview. but you would need an iPhoneX for iPhoneX appstore previews.
Thanks any help would be appreciated. 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B51i.png)

Comment: Can't you use the iPhone X simulator for recording?

Comment: There is only an option for screenshots only

Comment: You can use Quicktime to record a portion of the screen. Just fire up the application on the simulator and record the portion of the screen where the simulator is

Comment: My only problem is getting the correct resizing size for Apple AppStore

Comment: There is another way to do this. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797439/7842542

Comment: Doesn’t work on the iPhoneX

Comment: Apple won't currently accept a Video Preview in iPhone X resolution (1126 x  2436) so you need to resize such video to a different aspect ratio to get it into the iTunes Connect. If you don't have physical iPhone X, perhaps you are better off to make your footage on a different device.