# What's the flutter command for screen recording the simulator?

Tags: ios, flutter

Simple enough to screen record your app(an option on the emulator) in Android studio for an Android app. Searching around I can't find a way to record on the iOS simulator(In android Studio). I could use Quicktime but thought there might be a flutter command for it?

Comment: you can use terminal line command to record the simulator ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797990/capture-ios-simulator-video-for-app-preview?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take a screenshot of iOS Simulator or record a video, you can do it by using the utility `simctl` from the **Terminal** which allows us to control the simulator with commands.

To record video, you can do it only through **Terminal** by typing:

```
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <filename>.<file extension>
```

Replace `<filename>` with the name you want and `<file extension>` with `.mov`.

To stop recording, press `Control+C` to stop recording then check the file inside the Home folder (`Finder>Go>Home`)

The exported file is in **hevc** codec, if you want different codec, type the following to see the list:

```
xcrun simctl help io
```